# Having problems installing gurobi in Pycharm

Tags: python, gurobi

I've been trying to use gurobi in Pycharm. I've already downloaded gurobi and used my license. I am trying to install it via conda. So I install it in the terminal.

(pythonProject10) C:\Users\jakob\PycharmProjects\pythonProject10>conda install -c gurobi gurobi

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: -

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
|
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- gurobi -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

- feature:/win-64::__cuda==10.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.1

(pythonProject10) C:\Users\jakob\PycharmProjects\pythonProject10>

Not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gurobi doesn't support python 3.8 yet.  It works with python 3.7.

Comment: This is only true for conda packages.

Comment: So it would work if I uninstalled python/pycharm and installed the 3.7 version ?

Comment: @ Mattmitlen I tried to install it without conda, so I created a new project with virtualenv, then reinstalled Gurobi to see where it was installed and then tried to tell python in the terminal where it was installed. See picture https://imgur.com/a/0sjhY7Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no Python 3.8 package for Gurobi on conda, you can just run

```
python setup.py install
```

from the Gurobi home directory to install it into your current environment. This works just fine also for Python 3.8.

Comment: Sorry but I am quite sure what you are refering to when you say "Gurobi home directory"

Comment: I mean the Gurobi installation directory.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am very new to this. So I have guided myself to where Gurobi is installed https://imgur.com/a/FgqJv39 do I need to do something in here ?

Comment: Hello, I tried that but I get this error message: https://imgur.com/a/SebqnH6

Comment: I don't think you know what you're doing. I strongly recommend you work your way through some Python tutorials first. These are quite good: https://realpython.com/